# Hides the view when the button is clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button, radio-group

I have a radio group used to set data class properties. Here's how I've gone so far: I manually set the "bankDestination" view to invisible if proxy_bi_fast is checked. However the "bankDestination" view is still visible.

```
fun onRadioButtonClicked(view: View) {
        if (view is RadioButton) {
            val checked = view.isChecked

            when (view.getId()){
                R.id.proxy_BI_Fast ->
                    if (checked) {
                        binding.bankDestination.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

the related xml code:

```
                     <RadioGroup
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/account_number"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:text="@string/account_number"
                            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/proxy_BI_Fast"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:text="@string/proxy_bi_fast" />

                    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: I would recommend keeping all view's ID to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added onClick method in your proxy_BI_Fast radio button. Try adding that and then check.

Answer (score 0):

It wont' work `android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"` in the `RadioButton` instead of this you have to use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` on the `RadioGroup` as describe below.

```
  binding.rbGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            when (checkedId) {
                R.id.proxy_BI_Fast -> {
                    binding.bankDestination.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }
```